# Error C6308 happens when I compile this code, saying realloc can return NULL, and may cause memory leak

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, realloc

```
void inf_int:: Sub(const char num, const unsigned int index)    
    {
        if (this->length < index) {
            this->digits = (char*)realloc(this->digits, index + 1);     
            if (this->digits == NULL) {     
                cout << "Memory reallocation failed, the program will terminate." << endl;
    
                exit(0);
            }
    
            this->length = index;                   
            this->digits[this->length] = '\0';
        }
    
        if (this->digits[index - 1] < '0') {    
            this->digits[index - 1] = '0';
        }
    
        this->digits[index - 1] -= num - '0';   
        if (this->digits[index - 1] < '0') {    
            this->digits[index - 1] += 10;  
            Sub('1', index + 1);            
        }
    }
```

In the fourth line, the compiler returns error that realloc can return null. I have added the fifth line if in order to process the case, and exit the procedure in this case, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody give me any pointers on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Save the result to a temporary and only assign back to the original variable if non-null?

Comment: This should not be an error but only a warning. Best practices recommend to always free what have been allocated, but it does not really matter when you are about to abort the program: the end of the program will release any allocated memory. You have probably set a compiler option to handle (some?) warnings as fatal errors.

Comment: Why still use realloc if there is std::string or std::vector<char> for you to use? Naked malloc/free, new/delete should be considered flags for refactoring.

Comment: The error message explains it.   If `realloc()` fails then (1) it does not release the allocated memory (first argument) (2) it returns NULL.   So, if `realloc()` fails  `this->digits = (char*)realloc(this->digits, index + 1)` loses track of the previous value of `this->digits` without deallocating it - hence a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

The function `realloc` can return a null pointer in this case if to assign the return value of a function call to the initial pointer then the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost. You need to use an intermediate pointer as for example

```
        char *tmp = (char*)realloc(this->digits, index + 1);     
        if (tmp == NULL) {     
            cout << "Memory reallocation failed, the program will terminate." << endl;
            // free( this->digits ); provided that the destructor does not call free itself
            exit(0);
        }

        this->digits = tmp;
        //...
```